# float 32 from pandas rolling functions rather than float 64

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing some very long computations on continuous seismic data where efficiency is a big deal. I am trying to test if casting all the numpy arrays into float 32 rather than using the default float64 will yield significant speed ups, as double precision is probably not needed. One problem, however, is that I am using pandas rolling mean and rolling std as part of the processing which seems to automatically cast the results of the operation on the float32 array back into float64 defeating the purpose of the original recasting. For example,

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
r=np.random.rand(10000).astype(np.float32) # a float32 array
n=30 #window length for rolling operation
a=pd.rolling_mean(r,n)
```

now when I check a.dtype it is a float64. I could simply recast variable a back to float32 but this would probably increase run time rather than decrease it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure this is the problem though? Have you done some profiling? Also casting is going to cause a reallocation and copying of your data into another data structure, how will this help?

Comment: @EdChum The operations performed on massive np arrays is where the program spends the bulk of its time (apart from IO). In theory if I input float32 arrays rather than float64 into the operations it should perform faster, this is what I am trying to test. As for the reallocation and copying, the memory is not an issue and if the operations on the arrays is much faster, and the reallocation takes relatively little time it would be an overall speed up no? Am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

Comment: You could try that but I'd be a little surprised that you save anything after doing the conversion

Comment: this is currently not implemented (though not very hard to add). pull requests are welcome